# Can I assign a Future to a controller's attribute in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I need to get a list of values asynchronously from the server. The API's method returns a Future.

Of course I can create a callback and assign the result manually, I wonder if there's a way to delegate this to AngularDart?

```dart
class IndexPageController {
    var apps;
    EasyAPIClient api = new EasyAPIClient('/api/');


    IndexPageController() {
        _loadData();
    }


    _loadData() {
        api.getAppNames().then((app_names){
            apps = app_names;
        });
    }
}
```

What I'd like to have approximately:

```dart
class IndexPageController {
    var apps;
    EasyAPIClient api = new EasyAPIClient('/api/'); 

    IndexPageController() {
        _loadData();
    }

    _loadData() {   
        // this code executes successfully, 
        // however the template never receives the list.
        apps = api.getAppNames(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AngularDart doesn't currently support Futures/Streams in templates.

Comment: Is there any plans to support it?